# Why won't the final string show correct output when concatenate 2 string to a third one letter by letter?

Tags: c++, string, merge

```
 /* Write a program that would mix-and-merge two given strings (s1 and s2) into string s3 as follows:
 first character of s1, first character of s2, second character of s1, second character of s2, etc. */
```

I found this example exercise in the internet and i thought i would give it a try.
Everything seems to be ok and the code compiles without error but my "s3" string variable will not output anything and it will simply stay blank.

Funny to say but the problem seems to be here in the last line before return 0;

```
cout << s3;
```

If i do something like this:

```
cout << s3[0];
```

Or whatever index i want, it will show the correct character when the code is run which was joined from the other strings. So what is the problem?
Code here for reference:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    string s1, s2, s3;
    int i;
    int j = 0;

    cout << "Type in the first string: ";
    getline(cin, s1);
    cout << "Type in the second string: ";
    getline(cin, s2);

    for(i = 0; j < s1.size(); i += 2) // Merge first string by starting at index 0 and moving in 2s hence i += 2.
    {
        s3[i] = s1[j];
        ++j;
    }

    j = 0;

    for(i = 1; j < s1.size(); i +=2) // Merge second string by starting at index 1 hence i + 1 and again moving in 2s as to not overwrite an index that s1 put in.
    {
        s3[i] = s2[j];
        ++j;
    }


    cout << s3; // Problem is here?

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you resize `s3` to `s1.size() + s2.size()`? I wonder why your program does not crash at `s3[i] = s1[j]`

Comment: And what would that resizing do? Also why should my program crash here `s3[i] = s1[j]` isn't that valid? If no for what reason. Thanks.

Comment: "If pos is not greater than the string length, the function never throws exceptions (no-throw guarantee).
Otherwise, it causes undefined behavior." - this is from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator%5B%5D/

Comment: Alright i will do so thanks my friend.

Comment: I forgot to mention that string is constructed empty by default so it's size is 0 after construction

Comment: I did this `s1.size() + s2.size()` And now it shows me only the first character which is correct cout i need it to show all the characters and i don't understand why `cout << s3;` will not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accessing the `s3` string using the operator `[i]` with i bigger than the current length is undefined behavior.

You could try making `s3` big enough (e.g. fill with spaces) before your loops. Note that your current implementation only works if both strings are the same length.

Alternatively, try to think of a different way. e.g. the way you would do it if you had the strings `s1` and `s2` on little stacks of paper (with one letter on each piece) in front of you and wanted to merge them into a single stack.

Comment: "Alternatively, try to think of a different way. e.g. the way you would do it if you had the strings s1 and s2 on little stacks of paper (with one letter on each piece) in front of you and wanted to merge them into a single stack." I didn't get that part haha :P. I can visualize it but i cant think how to program it that way. could you help?

Comment: Here is one way: You could use one loop, incrementing `i`. Each time round the loop take the `i`th element from each of `s1` and `s2` and add it to the end of `s3`. You will need to add checks to make sure you don't go past the end of `s1` or `s2`. Stop the loop when you have reached the end of both `s1` and `s2`.

Comment: Could you tell me how to implement the checks?

Comment: Test for `i < s1.size()` to check if s1 still has characters to get. Your loop should check `i < s1.size() || i < s2.size()` but you still need to check inside the loop for `i < s1.size()` and `i < s2.size()` separately before you try to get characters from the two strings.

Answer (score 1):

Added just one line to your code and got this working:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    string s1, s2, s3;
    size_t i;
    size_t j = 0;

    cout << "Type in the first string: ";
    getline(cin, s1);
    cout << "Type in the second string: ";
    getline(cin, s2);

    s3.resize(s1.size() + s2.size());
    for(i = 0; j < s1.size(); i += 2) // Merge first string by starting at index 0 and moving in 2s hence i += 2.
    {
        s3[i] = s1[j];
        ++j;
    }

    j = 0;

    for(i = 1; j < s1.size(); i +=2) // Merge second string by starting at index 1 hence i + 1 and again moving in 2s as to not overwrite an index that s1 put in.
    {
        s3[i] = s2[j];
        ++j;
    }


    cout << s3; // Problem is here?

    return 0;
}
```

Although this works only for `s1` and `s2` of equal size.

Comment: Thanks my friend up voted as it works for me now too :P but one problem that i haven't solved is that it dose not pick characters after spaces even tho i have used getline instead of cin;
 Edit 2 yea it dosnt work if one string is bigger than the other as it only shows chars up to the size of the smallest one
Edit you say "Although this works only for s1 and s2 of equal size."

What difference it makes if s1 is different size from s2?

Comment: Don't know what you're talking about. The input `a b c` and `d e f` gives output `ad  be  cf`. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes you are correct the problem was that i added the space and other chars in the end of string 2 which is larger than string 1 in my input so it didn't register them and i thought it was the space. How can i fix it so any string size is ok?